# How can i fix the multiplication problem in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I wanted to vectorize the calculation of f since before it was taking too much of computing time but now I am running into a problem with * multiplicaiton

```matlab
function TCxy(M, d, SLL, Nt, Np)
    z0 = cosh(acosh(10^(SLL/20))/(2*M-1));
    A = TCa(M, z0);

    th = linspace(0, pi/2, Nt);
    phi = linspace(0, 2*pi, Np);

    [th, phi] = meshgrid(th, phi);

    % Vectorized computation of f
    p_vals = (1:M)';
    q_vals = (1:M)';
    
    f = zeros(size(th));
    
    for p = p_vals
        for q = q_vals
            f = f + A(p, q) * cos((2*p-1)*pi*d*sin(th).*cos(phi)) .* ...
                        cos((2*q-1)*pi*d*sin(th).*sin(phi));
        end
    end
```

To be able to run the TCxy(50,0.5,30,100,100)
you need the following function:

```matlab
function y = T(n, z)
    if n == 0
        y = ones(size(z));
    elseif n == 1
        y = z;
    else
        % Initialize the Chebyshev polynomials up to n
        T_prev = ones(size(z));
        T_current = z;
        
        for k = 2:n
            % Recurrence relation for Chebyshev polynomials
            T_next = 2 * z .* T_current - T_prev;
            
            % Update previous and current polynomials
            T_prev = T_current;
            T_current = T_next;
        end
        
        y = T_current;
    end
end
```

```matlab
function [A]=TCa(M,z0)

L = 2 * M;

for n = 1 : M
  for m = 1 : M

    A(n,m)=0;
    for p = 1 : M
      for q = 1 : M
        A(n,m) = A(n,m) + ...
            T(L-1,z0 * cos((p-.5)*pi/L) * ...
            cos((q-.5)*pi/L) ) * ...
            cos((2*pi/L)*(n-.5)*(p-.5)) * ...
            cos((2*pi/L)*(m-.5)*(q-.5));
      end;
    end;
    A(n,m) = A(n,m)*(4/L)^2;
    end;
end;
```

Here is the error:

```
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in
the second matrix. To operate on each element of the matrix individually, use TIMES (.*) for elementwise multiplication.

Error in TCxy (line 18)
            f = f + A(p, q) * cos((2*p-1)*pi*d*sin(th).*cos(phi)) .* ...
```

([error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A2XB.png))

Comment: Do you want [`times()` or `.*`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) instead of what you're currently using which is [`mtimes()` or `*`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html)?

Comment: I would like using .* but it gave the same error when i implemented it

Comment: Your error is near the start of your code, so I advise [edit]ing your question to simplify the code by removing everything after the `for` loop which is giving you the error message. Then also update the code so it's a [mcve] we can actually run. If I try and run your code I see that `Nt`, `Np`, `M`, and `A` are not defined, please define example inputs so we can run your code. Lastly, I'd be surprised if you receive the same error when using `.*` because that error specifically relates to using `*`

Comment: Updated, thank you for you feedback. Now it should give the same error i get

Comment: Remove the `'` in the definition of `p_vals` and `q_vals`. The transpose means you’re not iterating over the values in these vectors, because `for` iterates over columns.